# How to apply css transform to individual buttons?

Tags: css, css-animations

In my webpage, I'm displaying a table. In that each row contains three buttons. I want to apply click like feeling so I used css like

```
.historyButton{
    background: #339999;
    border:none;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.historyButton:active{
    background: #339999;
    border:none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: translateY(4px);
}
```

Using above, when I click one single button it applies 'transform' animation to all the buttons which have class 'historyButton'. But I want this transform animation only to the button I'm clicking. How can I achieve this? Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: *when I click one single button it applies 'transform' animation to all the buttons*  --> it's good if you can show us this behavior, as it shouldn't happen

Comment: The code you've posted works properly when I tested it on two `<a>` elements. Perhaps the mistake is somewhere else?

Comment: Thank you. I will look for other issue.